# How do I query by two columns with a self-referential relation with SQL/ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I've got a `Story` and a `Share` model. The `Story` belongs_to a `Share`, and a `Share` has_one `Story`. They both have timestamps. `Share` is self-referential, so it's got a `parent_id` column on it, and sometimes a share will be nested underneath another. And it's not infinitely nestable, just one level down.

Initially I've just been sorting on the `created_at` column of `Story`. But now I need to do something a little more complex. If the `Story` has a `Share` or nested shares, I'd like to sort on the `created_at` columns of those as well. The idea being that further activity on that `Story` (nested shares) would bump it up to the top of the order.

EDIT: Here's the solution:

```
SELECT * FROM stories
LEFT OUTER JOIN shares AS s1 ON stories.share_id = s1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN shares AS s2 ON s2.parent_id = s1.id
ORDERY BY s2.created_at DESC NULLS LAST, stories.created_at DESC
```

Or in ActiveRecord:

```
Story.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN shares AS s1 ON stories.share_id = s1.id').
      joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN shares AS s2 ON s2.parent_id = s1.id').
      order('s2.created_at DESC NULLS LAST, stories.created_at DESC')
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might want to add some test data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join Share twice. In SQL it would be something like that:

```
select * from stories
left outer join shares as s1 on s1.story_id=stories.id
left outer join shares as s2 on s1.parent_id=s2.id
order by greatest(s2.updated_at,s1.updated_at,stories.updated_at)
```

Don't know how to do that in Rails, try to experiment with :includes

Comment: Ah, very interesting. OK so the foreign key is actually on Story, not Share. So there's share_id column on Story. I switched it, and with one join it seems to work fine, however the second join doesn't seem to work right. In postgres console, after the first join I see the Story columns with the Share columns appended (joined) after them. But when I do the second join, a second set of Share columns get appended, but they're all empty. I'm going to edit the original post to show what I have so far.

Comment: Oh wait. Shouldn't it be `s1.id = s2.parent_id`? Hrm, the columns of the second join are still blank.

Comment: Oh nevermind, it does work. I'd just recently cleaned out the nested Share so there was only one at the bottom and I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: Alright. One last part; the ordering. I started with just the nested `created_at`, so that would be `s2.created_at`. If I do `s2.created_at DESC`, the two rows with values for `s2.created_at` are in the right order, but they're all the way at the bottom. It's putting the rows with that have `nulls` for that field ahead of the ones with actual values. How do stop that from happening?

Comment: OK, figured it out. Postgres has facility for switching how nulls are sorted. By default it's `NULLS FIRST`, so just change it to `NULLS LAST`. Solution above.

Comment: Crap, there's one more wrinkle. If there are multiple shares, this will create a new row for each story. So I need to unique by the story id. However, after much trial and error and reading, I've found that distinct really won't work with complex queries, most recommend doing sub-queries with GROUP By. I found this [example](http://nathansnoggin.blogspot.com/2009/04/select-distinct-with-order-by.html), I just don't know how to apply it to this situation.